# Docker swarm stack: Traefik with Whoami returns `404 page not found`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, traefik

I've tried to use the basic example guide in Traefik docs web, but always get error when check the WhoAmi service:

I should see the output of the whoami service (curl -H Host:whoami.volkonik.xyz http://whoami.volkonik.xyz). Something similar to:

```
Hostname: d7f919e54651
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 192.168.64.2
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: whoami.localhost
User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.64.1
X-Forwarded-Host: whoami.localhost
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: 7f0c797dbc51
X-Real-Ip: 192.168.64.1
```

But I get:

```
404 page not found
```

Regarding to my task I should use docker swarm with 3 managers use "docker stack" commands, not docker compose and deploy traefik with exposed whoami service.

Command that I use to deploy my stack: **deploy -c overflow.yml overflow**.
My overflow.yml:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2"
    command:
      #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.volkonik.xyz`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
```

Docker info:

```
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 5
 Server Version: 19.03.12
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: 5l5fmyv287ro7x07h5rhrzim5
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: zoiwzedomj7lbyvqh69rn9m64
  Managers: 3
  Nodes: 3
  Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8
  SubnetSize: 24
  Data Path Port: 4789
  Orchestration:
   Task History Retention Limit: 5
  Raft:
   Snapshot Interval: 10000
   Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
   Heartbeat Tick: 1
   Election Tick: 10
  Dispatcher:
   Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
  CA Configuration:
   Expiry Duration: 3 months
   Force Rotate: 0
  Autolock Managers: false
  Root Rotation In Progress: false
  Node Address: 164.90.229.118
  Manager Addresses:
   138.68.65.250:2377
   164.90.229.118:2377
   164.90.229.127:2377
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc version: dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.15.0-112-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 1
 Total Memory: 1.946GiB
 Name: nikolay-volkov-small-1
 ID: YARQ:QDCY:35IG:SNZQ:MUNG:UZL2:WBUK:N7Q5:P4C6:6FTV:52NU:7DTF
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: No swap limit support
```

Docker network ls:

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
7266d22942a1        bridge              bridge              local
edfbf6592868        docker_gwbridge     bridge              local
72f35302100b        host                host                local
hx6aj67pa4bz        ingress             overlay             swarm
038d3f36bede        none                null                local
rhksb2n1j235        overflow_default    overlay             swarm
```

docker stack ps overflow

```
ID                  NAME                     IMAGE                      NODE                     DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE             ERROR               PORTS
cnk96s94dj8c        overflow_traefik.1       traefik:v2.2               nikolay-volkov-small-2   Running             Running 16 minutes ago
wjziltuypmfj        overflow_whoami.1        containous/whoami:latest   nikolay-volkov-small-1   Running             Running 28 minutes ago`enter code here`
```

docker network inspect overflow_default:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "overflow_default",
        "Id": "rhksb2n1j235b3qkuvlgdrprp",
        "Created": "2020-08-15T14:21:20.194017073Z",
        "Scope": "swarm",
        "Driver": "overlay",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "10.0.2.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "10.0.2.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "61afaac4fff8c2474d7166c4227c776860081630c04f7c3a3403ef29b716f94d": {
                "Name": "overflow_whoami.1.wjziltuypmfj7vg0zuxlj5kva",
                "EndpointID": "5ce2f8cfb37f2294210bbb538576d485c7c3cf066d836771da6a002e5fbbbafe",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:03",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "lb-overflow_default": {
                "Name": "overflow_default-endpoint",
                "EndpointID": "d6453d2d9362bf95f3f34a06a8241e85410d3f8cf3ee0a6894baaecbe7348cea",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:02:04",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.2.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.driver.overlay.vxlanid_list": "4098"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "overflow"
        },
        "Peers": [
            {
                "Name": "995d8aecdcfe",
                "IP": "164.90.229.118"
            },
            {
                "Name": "853c9483a7b7",
                "IP": "164.90.229.127"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

docker service inspect overflow_whoami:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "tkbf0ucohva6eg76vzvfkhh6m",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 57011
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2020-08-15T14:21:20.020420896Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2020-08-15T14:49:19.975265202Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "overflow_whoami",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "containous/whoami",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "overflow"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "containous/whoami:latest@sha256:7d6a3c8f91470a23ef380320609ee6e69ac68d20bc804f3a1c6065fb56cfa34e",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "overflow",
                        "traefik.enable": "true",
                        "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints": "web",
                        "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule": "Host(`whoami.volkonik.xyz`)"
                    },
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "386",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "rhksb2n1j235b3qkuvlgdrprp",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "whoami"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip"
            }
        },
        "PreviousSpec": {
            "Name": "overflow_whoami",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "containous/whoami",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "overflow"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "containous/whoami:latest@sha256:7d6a3c8f91470a23ef380320609ee6e69ac68d20bc804f3a1c6065fb56cfa34e",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "overflow",
                        "traefik.enable": "true",
                        "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints": "web",
                        "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule": "Host(`whoami.volkonik.xyz`)"
                    },
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "386",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "rhksb2n1j235b3qkuvlgdrprp",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "whoami"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip"
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip"
            },
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "rhksb2n1j235b3qkuvlgdrprp",
                    "Addr": "10.0.2.2/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

docker service inspect overflow_traefik:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "xzpl81oco98onhvqxxkhdnbxz",
        "Version": {
            "Index": 57010
        },
        "CreatedAt": "2020-08-15T14:21:21.644144642Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "2020-08-15T14:49:18.348979648Z",
        "Spec": {
            "Name": "overflow_traefik",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "traefik:v2.2",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "overflow"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "traefik:v2.2@sha256:f5af5a5ce17fc3e353b507e8acce65d7f28126408a8c92dc3cac246d023dc9e8",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "overflow"
                    },
                    "Args": [
                        "--api.insecure=true",
                        "--providers.docker=true",
                        "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true",
                        "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false",
                        "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
                    ],
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "bind",
                            "Source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                            "Target": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                            "ReadOnly": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "StopGracePeriod": 10000000000,
                    "DNSConfig": {},
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "RestartPolicy": {
                    "Condition": "any",
                    "Delay": 5000000000,
                    "MaxAttempts": 0
                },
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "rhksb2n1j235b3qkuvlgdrprp",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "traefik"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "UpdateConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "RollbackConfig": {
                "Parallelism": 1,
                "FailureAction": "pause",
                "Monitor": 5000000000,
                "MaxFailureRatio": 0,
                "Order": "stop-first"
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 80,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 8080,
                        "PublishedPort": 8080,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "PreviousSpec": {
            "Name": "overflow_traefik",
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.stack.image": "traefik:v2.2",
                "com.docker.stack.namespace": "overflow"
            },
            "TaskTemplate": {
                "ContainerSpec": {
                    "Image": "traefik:v2.2@sha256:f5af5a5ce17fc3e353b507e8acce65d7f28126408a8c92dc3cac246d023dc9e8",
                    "Labels": {
                        "com.docker.stack.namespace": "overflow"
                    },
                    "Args": [
                        "--api.insecure=true",
                        "--providers.docker=true",
                        "--providers.docker.swarmMode=true",
                        "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false",
                        "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
                    ],
                    "Privileges": {
                        "CredentialSpec": null,
                        "SELinuxContext": null
                    },
                    "Mounts": [
                        {
                            "Type": "bind",
                            "Source": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                            "Target": "/var/run/docker.sock",
                            "ReadOnly": true
                        }
                    ],
                    "Isolation": "default"
                },
                "Resources": {},
                "Placement": {
                    "Platforms": [
                        {
                            "Architecture": "amd64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "OS": "linux"
                        },
                        {
                            "Architecture": "arm64",
                            "OS": "linux"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Networks": [
                    {
                        "Target": "rhksb2n1j235b3qkuvlgdrprp",
                        "Aliases": [
                            "traefik"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "ForceUpdate": 0,
                "Runtime": "container"
            },
            "Mode": {
                "Replicated": {
                    "Replicas": 1
                }
            },
            "EndpointSpec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 80,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 8080,
                        "PublishedPort": 8080,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Endpoint": {
            "Spec": {
                "Mode": "vip",
                "Ports": [
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 80,
                        "PublishedPort": 80,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    },
                    {
                        "Protocol": "tcp",
                        "TargetPort": 8080,
                        "PublishedPort": 8080,
                        "PublishMode": "ingress"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Ports": [
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 80,
                    "PublishedPort": 80,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                },
                {
                    "Protocol": "tcp",
                    "TargetPort": 8080,
                    "PublishedPort": 8080,
                    "PublishMode": "ingress"
                }
            ],
            "VirtualIPs": [
                {
                    "NetworkID": "hx6aj67pa4bz4nu70dyrdatq6",
                    "Addr": "10.11.0.12/16"
                },
                {
                    "NetworkID": "rhksb2n1j235b3qkuvlgdrprp",
                    "Addr": "10.0.2.5/24"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Hi there, any suggestions? I see that traefik does not see the Whoami service, but I do not know why.